# Prevent phone from turning off video during call

Tags: android-12, viber-messenger, video-calling

I got a new Samsung phone (Galaxy A32 5G) and it has a "feature" that I find disappointing.

I was in a video call with my grandmother, using Viber. When I switched to another app (I wanted to look up something on my calendar), the video stream automatically stopped. When I switched back to Viber, I was able to turn on my camera again, after some fumbling; my grandmother did not manage to turn on hers, although I cannot say if it really was impossible, or if she didn't find the right button. In any case, it greatly distressed my grandmother (who is very afraid of "breaking" something on her phone) and was also very unwelcome for me.

On my old phone (Moto X4), when I switched between apps, Viber continued transmitting video. I think there was a small window still showing the other person, or maybe the other person just kept seeing me, and when I switched back, I saw them again.

My questions are:

- Is the problem related to the Samsung UI (the Moto X4 was, I believe, very close to a stock Android), or to the fact that the new phone uses a more recent version of Android? It is on Android 12, and I noticed that, when asking for permissions, it only lists the options "deny", "allow once" or "allow while the apps is running", but not just "allow" - maybe Viber loses camera permissions when I switch?
- Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
- If I cannot turn it off on this phone (or if turning it off requires rooting), would returning this phone and buying another one (e.g. a current model of a Motorola-brand phone) solve the problem?

Comment: Looks like it's [a restriction since Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services).

Comment: @AndrewT. the mystery grows deeper then! The page you linked is about both microphone and camera, and it seems that both should work the same way. My microphone continued working when Viber was in the background, only the camera stopped.